# mvn versions:use-releases only find release in .m2 but could not find in repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, release, snapshot, versions-maven-plugin

I need to replace my module's parent and dependent modules' snapshot version with release version for the process of release.

First, I run "mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot=true versions:commit" to remove my module's snapshot version. It works well.

Next, I run "mvn versions:use-releases -DprocessParent=true versions:commit". It does not do anything. From the output of mvn,

```
[INFO] artifact com.xxxxx:parent: checking for updates from maven-group
[INFO] artifact com.xxxxx:parent: checking for updates from central
```

It seems that it checks my repo, "maven-group", but it could not find it? I do have parent release verion in "maven-group", 0.0.3. the snapshot version in my pom is 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.

However, if I build the release version of my parent in my local machine (the 0.0.3 of parent will be in .m2), this command can update parent module from 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT. Same thing for dependent module. So it looks to me that versions:use-release only only find the release version info in .m2.

Here is my repo in pom. I use nexus repo. maven-group is the entry for release and snapshot repo.

```
<repository>
    <id>maven-group</id>
    <url>http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
</repository>
```

Do anyone have some ideas? I have tried to add

```
<id>maven-group</id>
<url>http://192.168.xxx.xx:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>     
<snapshots>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
   <enabled>true</enabled>"
</releases>"
```

for maven-group or directly use maven-releases or maven-snapshots repo in pom file. But none of them works.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-U` flag; that will force it to check for updates on the remote repository.

E.g.,

```
mvn -U versions:use-releases -DprocessParent=true versions:commit
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  I have both the snapshot version and release version of my parent pom in my local `~/.m2/repository`.  But it doesn't update.

It appears that perhaps the command only uses the project version number for the parent version?  I could be misreading this PR that claims to have fixed this exact issue.  https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/commit/83db71783d8adf5a1b410f9d609a2ba03e6e49d8

But my parent pom is independent of my repo version numbers (I use a company wide shared parent pom that all my repos share).  I assume this is fairly standard behavior though.

Comment: You should have the release version available in your remote repo.

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html

Comment: I also have the release version in my remote repo.  My repo is a private repo running Sonatype nexus which is configured via my ~/.m2/settings.xml.  But, I couldn't get this command to work for me personally.  I certainly could be doing something wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little odd syntax wise, but I found a command that works. This command will update the parent pom version ONLY if it is a SNAPSHOT AND the exact release version is available.  This disables incrementing the version itself since I'm using this in a release script and I want developers to change the version, but I don't want developers to have to remove the `-SNAPSHOT` after a release of the parent pom.  That is just busy work and I'm often one of those developers.  :)

```
mvn -DallowMajorUpdates=false -DallowMinorUpdates=false \
   -DallowIncrementalUpdates=false versions:update-parent
```

See [maven versions:update-parent](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) docs for details